# sql join 2 tables on column x and merge field z

Tags: mysql, sql-server

lets take an example - i have 2 data tables, table "books" with columns "shelfId" and "text", and table "shelves" with column "Id". I want to join these two tables on books.shelfId == shelves.Id, and as a result, i want to see a new table with 2 columns - column 1 has unique values of Ids, and column 2 has merged values of books.text with same books.shelfId values and separated by comma or something else, i.e. :

[image: tables example]

Is it possible to write such sql select to get what i need ?

Comment: Not clear mysql or sql-server, but its looks like simple question using `FOR XML` to concatenate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c96dfa/1

```
SELECT shelfid as id, GROUP_CONCAT(text) AS text
FROM books
GROUP BY shelfid
```